# Insert parsed string per column and not per row in MSSql

Tags: sql-server, parsing, insert

I previously asked a question with regards to parsing a string wherein the string is comma and semi colon separated. I understand the flow and did a good job editing it a little to suit my needs. Now my problem is the result that is being returned is in a single column instead of one part of the parsed data per column.

```
351856040520298
241111
1G
141007024755
A
1437.2453N
12100.2887E
3.10
206
0.8
21010000
2G
141007024755
10
43.6
14.08
00.18
273295019.6
```

The above is the result. All of them in 1 column named Method 2

Now what I want to show is like 1 data 1 column

```
351856040520298 |241111 |1G | 141007024755 |A |1437.2453N |12100.2887E |3.10 |206 |0.8 |21010000 |2G |141007024755 |10 |43.6 |14.08 |00.18 |273295019.6
```

something like the above is what I want.

**Here's the code**

```
---- Method 2 : split string based on both semi colon and comma

 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Parserstring] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(max) )
 RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(max) )
 AS
 BEGIN

DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(max)

WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                            ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                            LEN(@StringInput)))
    SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                 ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput), 0),
                                 LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

    INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
    VALUES ( @String )
END

RETURN
 END

Go
```

Comment: to produce a output table you do must declare the structure of the output but it looks like you can't know how many columns could be in the input string so you cannot do that that way...

Answer (score 0):

I used dynamic query and `cursor` to get the expected result. Try this and tell me is it fulfill your requirement.

Change '`SELECT Column1 FROM YourTableName`' query with your select query for a single column with multo rows.

```
DECLARE @Current VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR
   SELECT Column1 FROM YourTableName

    SET @QueryString = 'SELECT '

    OPEN Cursor1
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @Current

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN  
        FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @Current
        SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ISNULL(@Current, 'NULL') + ', '
    END

    CLOSE Cursor1
    DEALLOCATE Cursor1

    SELECT @QueryString = SUBSTRING(@QueryString, 0, LEN(@QueryString) - 1)
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QueryString
```

Comment: Is this a Stored Proc? Or Function? How will I set it up?